# Give weight to fields elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch index containing products, I am trying to create a search list products in function of a text field.

A sort example fo the dataset

`{"name": "foo", "count": 10}`
`{"name": "bar", "count": 5}`
`{"name": "foo bar"}`
`{"name": "foo baz", "count": 20}`

At the beginning, I was requesting with.

```
GET /product
/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {"name": "foo"}
  }
}
```

It was working great but now I want to add weight on some products (the `count` field)

I am using this query

```
GET /product/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": {"name": "foo bar"}
      },
      "field_value_factor": {
        "field": "count",
        "missing": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but with this query first I have `foo`, then `bar` and then `foo bar` seems that the name match have less importance than the count, I would like to have `foo bar` then `foo` and `bar`

But looking for `foo` I would like `foo baz`, `foo` and `foo bar`

Comment: I think the easiest way to avoid this behavior would be to boost the name field in your query. You can also tune the field_value_factor with     "factor": 1.0, "modifier": "sqrt" to lower his importance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But looking for foo I would like foo baz, foo and foo bar

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result

Refer [function score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#query-dsl-function-score-query) to get detailed explanation.

**Index Data:**

```
{"name": "foo", "count": 10} 
{"name": "bar", "count": 5} 
{"name": "foo bar"} 
{"name": "foo baz", "count": 20}
```

**Search Query:**

> But looking for foo I would like foo baz, foo and foo bar

```
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "name": {
                                    "query": "foo"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "functions": [
                {
                    "field_value_factor": {
                        "field": "count",
                        "factor": 1.0,
                        "missing": 0
                    }
                }
            ],
            "boost_mode": "multiply"
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_64169215",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 6.2774796,
        "_source": {
          "name": "foo baz",
          "count": 20
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "stof_64169215",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 4.1299205,
        "_source": {
          "name": "foo",
          "count": 10
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "stof_64169215",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "name": "foo bar"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Update 1:**

> I would like to have foo bar then foo and bar

**Search Query:**

```
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "name": {
                                    "query": "foo bar"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "functions": [
                {
                    "field_value_factor": {
                        "field": "count",
                        "factor": 1.0,
                        "missing": 0,
                        "modifier": "sqrt"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "boost_mode": "sum"
        }
    }
}
```

**Explain API Result:**

To understand the above Search Query, you need to understand how the score is calculated for a query.

1. The search is made against `"name": "foo bar"`, that should ideally return `foo bar` then `foo` and then `bar`. And with normal match query against `foo bar` (and no function score query), you will get your results.
2. Now according to your use case, you want to add weight on the `count` field, for which you used [Function score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html), that allows you to modify the score of documents that are retrieved by a query.
3. Furthermore, several functions can be combined. The function_score query provides several types of score functions. The [field_value_factor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-field-value-factor) function allows you to use a field from a document to influence the score.
4. In the field_value_factor, there are several options :

> factor - Optional factor to multiply the field value with, defaults to
> 1

> modifier - Modifier to apply to the field value
> missing - Value used if the document doesn’t have that field.

The following formula for scoring is generated :

> sqrt(1.0 * doc['count'].value)

Now, for the document containing `foo bar`, there is no `count` field, so missing value(defined in the query i.e. `9`) is to be used. For which the score will be `sqrt(1.0 * 9) = 3.0`.

**If you take any missing value less than 9, then the order of the result will change. Because the score for the `count` field will vary (when you give missing value as `0`, then `foo bar`, gets score only on the basis of `match` query and no score gets added from the field_value_factor). And the final score is calculated based on both `match` query + `field_value_factor` (on `count` field). So the total score of `foo bar`, will be less than other documents.**

For example: For `foo bar`, final score is calculated as `0.78038335+3.0=3.7803833`. Please go through this below result, to get a detailed understanding of how scoring is calculated.

Please go through this blog to understand [how scoring works in elasticsearch](https://www.compose.com/articles/how-scoring-works-in-elasticsearch/)

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 3,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 3.7803833,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_shard": "[stof_64169215][0]",
        "_node": "fVeabsK0Q1GnCZ_8oROXjA",
        "_index": "stof_64169215",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 3.7803833,
        "_source": {
          "name": "foo bar"
        },
        "_explanation": {
          "value": 3.7803833,
          "description": "sum of",
          "details": [
            {
              "value": 0.78038335,
              "description": "sum of:",
              "details": [
                {
                  "value": 0.39019167,
                  "description": "weight(name:foo in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 0.39019167,
                      "description": "score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",
                      "details": [
                        {
                          "value": 2.2,
                          "description": "boost",
                          "details": []
                        },
                        {
                          "value": 0.47000363,
                          "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                          "details": [
                            {
                              "value": 2,
                              "description": "n, number of documents containing term",
                              "details": []
                            },
                            {
                              "value": 3,
                              "description": "N, total number of documents with field",
                              "details": []
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value": 0.37735844,
                          "description": "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                          "details": [
                            {
                              "value": 1.0,
                              "description": "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                              "details": []
                            },
                            {
                              "value": 1.2,
                              "description": "k1, term saturation parameter",
                              "details": []
                            },
                            {
                              "value": 0.75,
                              "description": "b, length normalization parameter",
                              "details": []
                            },
                            {
                              "value": 2.0,
                              "description": "dl, length of field",
                              "details": []
                            },
                            {
                              "value": 1.3333334,
                              "description": "avgdl, average length of field",
                              "details": []
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "value": 0.39019167,
                  "description": "weight(name:bar in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 0.39019167,
                      "description": "score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",
                      "details": [
                        {
                          "value": 2.2,
                          "description": "boost",
                          "details": []
                        },
                        {
                          "value": 0.47000363,
                          "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                          "details": [
                            {
                              "value": 2,
                              "description": "n, number of documents containing term",
                              "details": []
                            },
                            {
                              "value": 3,
                              "description": "N, total number of documents with field",
                              "details": []
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value": 0.37735844,
                          "description": "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                          "details": [
                            {
                              "value": 1.0,
                              "description": "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                              "details": []
                            },
                            {
                              "value": 1.2,
                              "description": "k1, term saturation parameter",
                              "details": []
                            },
                            {
                              "value": 0.75,
                              "description": "b, length normalization parameter",
                              "details": []
                            },
                            {
                              "value": 2.0,
                              "description": "dl, length of field",
                              "details": []
                            },
                            {
                              "value": 1.3333334,
                              "description": "avgdl, average length of field",
                              "details": []
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "value": 3.0,
              "description": "min of:",
              "details": [
                {
                  "value": 3.0,
                  "description": "field value function: sqrt(doc['count'].value?:9.0 * factor=1.0)",
                  "details": []
                },
                {
                  "value": 3.4028235E38,
                  "description": "maxBoost",
                  "details": []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_shard": "[stof_64169215][0]",
        "_node": "fVeabsK0Q1GnCZ_8oROXjA",
        "_index": "stof_64169215",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 3.685826,
        "_source": {
          "name": "foo",
          "count": 10
        },
        "_explanation": {
          "value": 3.685826,
          "description": "sum of",
          "details": [
            {
              "value": 0.52354836,
              "description": "sum of:",
              "details": [
                {
                  "value": 0.52354836,
                  "description": "weight(name:foo in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 0.52354836,
                      "description": "score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",
                      "details": [
                        {
                          "value": 2.2,
                          "description": "boost",
                          "details": []
                        },
                        {
                          "value": 0.47000363,
                          "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                          "details": [
                            {
                              "value": 2,
                              "description": "n, number of documents containing term",
                              "details": []
                            },
                            {
                              "value": 3,
                              "description": "N, total number of documents with field",
                              "details": []
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value": 0.50632906,
                          "description": "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                          "details": [
                            {
                              "value": 1.0,
                              "description": "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                              "details": []
                            },
                            {
                              "value": 1.2,
                              "description": "k1, term saturation parameter",
                              "details": []
                            },
                            {
                              "value": 0.75,
                              "description": "b, length normalization parameter",
                              "details": []
                            },
                            {
                              "value": 1.0,
                              "description": "dl, length of field",
                              "details": []
                            },
                            {
                              "value": 1.3333334,
                              "description": "avgdl, average length of field",
                              "details": []
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "value": 3.1622777,
              "description": "min of:",
              "details": [
                {
                  "value": 3.1622777,
                  "description": "field value function: sqrt(doc['count'].value?:9.0 * factor=1.0)",
                  "details": []
                },
                {
                  "value": 3.4028235E38,
                  "description": "maxBoost",
                  "details": []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_shard": "[stof_64169215][0]",
        "_node": "fVeabsK0Q1GnCZ_8oROXjA",
        "_index": "stof_64169215",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 2.7596164,
        "_source": {
          "name": "bar",
          "count": 5
        },
        "_explanation": {
          "value": 2.7596164,
          "description": "sum of",
          "details": [
            {
              "value": 0.52354836,
              "description": "sum of:",
              "details": [
                {
                  "value": 0.52354836,
                  "description": "weight(name:bar in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 0.52354836,
                      "description": "score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",
                      "details": [
                        {
                          "value": 2.2,
                          "description": "boost",
                          "details": []
                        },
                        {
                          "value": 0.47000363,
                          "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                          "details": [
                            {
                              "value": 2,
                              "description": "n, number of documents containing term",
                              "details": []
                            },
                            {
                              "value": 3,
                              "description": "N, total number of documents with field",
                              "details": []
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value": 0.50632906,
                          "description": "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                          "details": [
                            {
                              "value": 1.0,
                              "description": "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                              "details": []
                            },
                            {
                              "value": 1.2,
                              "description": "k1, term saturation parameter",
                              "details": []
                            },
                            {
                              "value": 0.75,
                              "description": "b, length normalization parameter",
                              "details": []
                            },
                            {
                              "value": 1.0,
                              "description": "dl, length of field",
                              "details": []
                            },
                            {
                              "value": 1.3333334,
                              "description": "avgdl, average length of field",
                              "details": []
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "value": 2.236068,
              "description": "min of:",
              "details": [
                {
                  "value": 2.236068,
                  "description": "field value function: sqrt(doc['count'].value?:9.0 * factor=1.0)",
                  "details": []
                },
                {
                  "value": 3.4028235E38,
                  "description": "maxBoost",
                  "details": []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_64169215",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 3.7803833,
        "_source": {
          "name": "foo bar"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "stof_64169215",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 3.685826,
        "_source": {
          "name": "foo",
          "count": 10
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "stof_64169215",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 2.7596164,
        "_source": {
          "name": "bar",
          "count": 5
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @Ajouve did you get a chance to go through my answer looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Comment: thanks but with `foo bar` I do not have the expected result match should have more weight

Comment: @Ajouve thanks for your reply :) But can you please confirm that if the second part of your question **But looking for foo I would like foo baz, foo and foo bar** is resolved or not (by using the above search query)

Comment: @Ajouve please go through my updated answer, and let me know if this was your issue ? I have deleted `foo baz` document for the updated search query so that you get a clear view of what you are trying to achieve)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your search request :

```
  "sort": [
    {
      "name.keyword": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    "_score"
  ],
```

Your full search looks like this :

```
GET product/_search
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "name.keyword": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    "_score"
  ], 
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": {"name": "foo bar"}
      },
      "field_value_factor": {
        "field": "count",
        "missing": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```